# T(n) = 2T(n/4) + sqrt(n)

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence-relation

T(n) = 2T(n/4) + sqrt(n)
I am trying to solve this question and ended up with the answer O(√n.log√n). But when I checked online the answer was supposed to be O(√n.logn) or √n.logn base 4. I am not sure how to remove the square root from n.

Comment: Please explain the steps you did to arrive at your answer.  What is the actual recurrence you're trying to solve?  Please add it to your question.

Comment: There *must* be a typo in the question. Please fix. Anyway, $O(\sqrt n\log\sqrt n)=O(\sqrt n\log n)$.

Comment: Yes, there was a typo. I am so sorry for that. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $T(n)=\sqrt n\log n$, $$T(n)-2T\left(\dfrac n4\right)=\sqrt n\log n-2\sqrt{\frac n4}\log\frac n4
\\=\sqrt n\log 4.$$

Comment: Thank you so much, I realised where I went wrong.

Answer (score -2):

Given: T(n) = 2T(n/4) + sqrt(2)

Complexity should be sqrt(n) => n^(1/2).

Please let me know whether the following derivation makes any sense.

[image]

Comment: Please transcribe your calculations.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes I understood both of the ways.

Comment: As per your first question(which you have updated later) I have given the answer. An up vote is really appreciated. @Crack_on_life

Comment: I know, I also wanted to give an up vote here because your answer helped a lot but I am not allowed to up vote yet. I need 15 reputation or something. I am really sorry for that.